# How to find locations of exact matches of a string in a long string of billion of letters efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bioinformatics

I have millions of strings and I want to check the locations of exact matches of each string in another collection of billions of strings. What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: With the information you provided you're limiting the set of people who can help you to those who know what FASTA and HG38 look like. It would be beneficial to add some sample data (and how it's structured within the filesystem) to get a wider range of responses.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple answers to this question.

1. You could use a hash function and traverse the whole human genome trying to match the hash of a subsequence the length of your sequence to the hash of your sequence if they match you have your sequence at your index. The [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) is O(n) where n is the size of the human genome. Take special care that your sequence is not long enough to overflow the integers.
2. You could use a variant of the brute force approach to string matching invented simultaneously by James H. Morris, Vaughan Pratt and Donald Knuth. The [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) starts to check for a match at each index and whenever it fails it checks for a table where the next index to start the matching starts. It is O(n) as well and has a better worst case complexity than RK (read [this article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)).
3. You could use the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm#cite_note-2) which is very similar to the previous algorithm. It starts by computing some shifts and then tries to match at some index conveniently jumping others. It is O(n) as well and has better worst case complexity than RK (read [the same article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)).

I suggest using Rabin-Karp algorithm as for me it seems easier to grasp (However I could be biased: [NIH Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here))

Comment: I'll freely admit that I'm no expert on search algorithms; but @Kaymar is looking for "one pattern", the wikipedia article at the top of the search results you provided suggests that KMP or Boyer-Moore would be more efficient with a single search pattern?

Comment: I quote "The essential benefit achieved by using a rolling hash such as the Rabin fingerprint is that it is possible to compute the hash value of the next substring from the previous one by doing only a constant number of operations, independent of the substrings' lengths." There exists a variant of the naive algorithm which is O(n+m) hence O(n) (n > m). It is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Hash_function_used).

Comment: @tink KMP and Boyer-Moore seem very appropriate as well, I add them to the answer